# Caching JSON results in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching

I am trying to cache an action that returns a json file, with this line

```
  caches_page :events, :cache_path => '/events.json', :expires_in => 1.hour  

  def events
    respond_to do |format|     

  format.text do
    render plain: result
    response.content_type # => "text/plain"
  end

  format.json do
    render json: result
  end      
end
```

But when I send a post to http://localhost:5000 the result is not cached.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4, `caches_page` will not work, as it's been removed. Here's a [link to the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#basic-caching), as well as a [blog post](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) by DHH explaining key-based caching in Rails.

If you truly still want to use `caches_page` you're going to have to use the actionpack-page_caching gem which can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching)